# Как создать последовательности из нормально и равномерно распределенных чисел?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Здравствуйте! Дело обстоит так:  
Имеются две задачи в которых будут сравниваться числа из двух последовательностей (в первой задаче числа в последовательностях распределены по нормальному закону, а в другой равномерно). Вот и возник вопрос: как создать эти две последовательности?
 Имеется в ввиду можно ли это сделать например командами как в маткаде типа:

```
N:= rnd (N, 0, 1),
```

без создания целой програмки для генератора случайных чисел?

Answer (score 5):

Есть простой метод обратной функции. Грубо говоря можно подставлять выход равномерно распределенного ГСЧ на интервале [0,1] на вход функции обратной необходимой функции распределения и в результате получать выборку с заданным распределением из равномерного.

Однако нормальное распределение на [0,1] проще получить на основании центральной предельной теоремы просто складывая несколько случайных чисел и затем нормируя их по соответствующей формуле.[image]

Где S_n cумма нескольких случайных чисел, n количество слагаемых в сумме, mu математическое ожидание ГСЧ, sigma корень из дисперсии выборки(СКО).

Answer (score 0):

И да, и нет: стандартные средства выдадут равномерное распределение случайной величины.
Чтоб получить нормальное - есть алгоритмы, реализующие это (переводят равномерное - в нормальное с заданными мат. ожиданием и дисперсией)

P.S. Возможно, есть готовые решения в составе каких-то математических библиотек, не подскажу